# ListFragment and context

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listfragment, android-context

I am working for the first time with ListFragments. I want to display data from a sqlite database.

My problem: I can't retrieve the context.

I have tried this.getActivity() in my class which extends ListFragment- but the context is null.

Then I have tried to save the context of my first activity(the ui which is displayed after starting the app) of my application as a static variable. But is this the right context?

```
static Context context; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Setting the context
        context = this; 

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
```

When I query the database I don't get any exceptions but the cursor is always empty. I have looked into my sqlite database - I have three rows of data (so the cursor should not be empty).

My code for querying the data from the database:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
        try{
            open();
            cursor = database.rawQuery("select _id, surname, prename, street, zipcode, telephone, email from "+Database.getMyDbTable()+";", null);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get list");
            CharSequence text = "Die Liste kann nicht erstellt werden!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor "+cursor); 
        close();
```

How do I get the right context?

Comment: I think that you are doing something wrong with your fragment. Is it properly added to your activity? And is it shown when you are trying to do this.getActivity()? It whouldn't be null.

Comment: I have tested my ListFragment with an array of string values - these are displayed in my app - I have no crashes. Does anyone know a good tutorial for working with ListFragment - I have to admit that I have still troubles with understanding the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this tutorial, which was quite helpful (as I wanted to have a Tab Layout combined with a list):

https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/Android-List-Fragment-Tutorial

I have modified the onCreate method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //Getting the data from the Database
        Context myContext = getActivity();           
        Log.d(TAG, "Context "+myContext);

        contactListManager = new ContactList(myContext);
        Log.d(TAG, "ContactListManager "+contactListManager);

        Cursor cursor =  contactListManager.fetchAllItems();
        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor "+cursor);
```

with this code I can access my database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! I confirmed that I can also solve the same issue by using...

Context myContext = getActivity();

Apparently ListPreference(this) will not work from inside of a PreferenceFragment.